# For loop in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to compute the matrix's complement but ran into a problem.

```
c = np.array([[1, 0], [13, 34]])

def rev(m):
    x = m
    for i in range(len(m)):
        for j in range(len(m)):
            m_new = np.delete(m, i, axis=0)
            m_new = np.delete(m_new, j, axis=1)
            x[i][j] = m_new
    print(x)
```

I wanted output:

```
[34, 13], [0, 1]
```

but instead I got this:

```
[34, 13], [13, 34]
```

It seems like `for` loops are working only in `j=0`.

When I make a little modification in code and add `+10` to `x[i][j]`

```
def rev(m):
    x = m
    for i in range(len(m)):
        for j in range(len(m)):
            m_new = np.delete(m, i, axis=0)
            m_new = np.delete(m_new, j, axis=1)
            x[i][j] = m_new + 10
    print(x)
```

I got this:

```
[44, 23], [33, 54]
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Anyone can to explain me why I got this output?

Comment: What do you expect np.delete to do?

Comment: With `x=m` both variab,es reference the same array.  Changes to `x[i,j]` also change `m`.  `x=m.copy()` might correct this behavior, though I still wouldn't recommend iteration like this, especially with the reoeated `np.delete` (an expensive numpy operation).

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of numpy is to avoid manual manipulation of individual elements in arrays/matrices.  If you need a for-loop on a numpy array, you're probably doing it wrong.

```
c[::-1,::-1]

array([[34, 13],
       [ 0,  1]])
```